# persist java LocalDate in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, jdbc, mysql-connector

I'm writing a java client application using: SE 8, MySQL 5.6 (Connector/J 5.1), JPA 2.1. when I try to persist an entity with an ID (int Auto-increment), date (LocalDate). it throw an Exception says:

```
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect date value: '\xAC\xED\x00\x05sr\x00\x0Djava.time.Ser\x95]\x84\xBA\x1B"H\xB2\x0C\x00\x00xpw\x07\x03\x00\x00\x07\xDF\x03\x06x' for column 'date' at row 1
```

does MySQL (I mean The Connector) do not support the new Date and Time API or What. if so What Can I do??

```
@Entity
@Table(schema="app")
public class Run implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;                     //number of connections

    private LocalDate date;
```

Comment: use a java.sql.Date for sql related Dates ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Registering the custom converter should help you solve your issue

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDatePersistenceConverter implements
    AttributeConverter<LocalDate, Date> {
    @Override
    public java.sql.Date convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDate entityValue) {
        return java.sql.Date.valueOf(entityValue);
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDate convertToEntityAttribute(java.sql.Date databaseValue) {
        return databaseValue.toLocalDate();
    }
}
```

more about converting the LocalDate [info](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/montanajava/archive/2014/06/17/using-java-8-datetime-classes-jpa) and some more about using the [converters](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/2013/10/jpa-21-how-to-implement-type-converter.html)

Comment: That's exactly what I was locking for, Thanks a lot Man

Comment: np, glad it helped :)

Comment: It should be generic and with null check

Answer (score 7):

AttributeConverter is also generic:

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDatePersistenceConverter implements
        AttributeConverter<LocalDate, Date> {
    @Override
    public Date convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDate entityValue) {
        return java.sql.Date.valueOf(entityValue);
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDate convertToEntityAttribute(Date databaseValue) {
        return databaseValue.toLocalDate();
    }

}
```

Comment: And don't forget the null check, null in is null out

Answer (score 3):

If working with hibernate I just found [here](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-5-date-and-time/) that also one can take advantage of Java 8 support shipped in a separate jar file called hibernate-java8.jar. So basically you can just add something like  this in your pom and be ready to go:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I use EclipseLink not hibernate

Comment: Ok, didnt realize, just thought someone might use this approach though