# Grails Mapping LocalDateTime of Java 8 domain objects to Gorm

Tags: hibernate, grails, java-8, persistence, grails-orm

Java 8 gives the java.time API.

I am using a grails application, I want to use java.time for properties of my domain classes.

I need to map for instance the LocalDateTime to the DATE/DATETIME on GORM which is built on top of Hibernate.

How can I persist my mappings?

I see a solution, that I can use jadira, and establish static mappings for my attributs.

However is there another way?

Please any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `user type` mapping. See [the docs](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/ref/Database%20Mapping/Usage.html). That should remove the need to explicitly map all instances individually.

To go further, I would take the `grails-joda-time` plugin sources and try to make a `jave.time` version. And even try to make (and submit a pull request) a version that would support both `joda-time` and `java.time`.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used gorm, but if we were to speak hibernate only (and I guess that it should be applicable), you would be able to follow two path.

One, if you are using or if you're able to upgrade to hibernate 5, than you can include the [`hibernate-java8`](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.hibernate%7Chibernate-java8%7C5.1.0.Final%7Cjar)

> Support for using Java8 specific data-types such as any of the JSR 310
>   Date/Time types in domain model.

Otherwise, you would have to write your own type as explained [here](http://blog.progs.be/550/java-time-hibernate), and use it e.g. like

```
@Type(type="your.custom.LocalDateTimeUserType")
private LocalDateTime date;
```

Finally, `gorm` is implementing the `JPA` specification, you can implement a [converter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28897481/1000933)

Comment: I use groovy on grails 3.0.10 so I am not sure if I can update Hibernate to 5, or I am wrong?

Comment: For the second way you suggest me, it is an actual mapping between domain objects to sql objects through Hibernate, not through Gorm. I will try to see if it could be applicable

Comment: You can use Hibernate 5 on Grails 3.0.10.
You have to upgrade to GORM 5 and then select Hibernate 5 for the implementation. See http://grails.github.io/grails-data-mapping/5.0.x/hibernate/manual/index.html for more information