# Date Format with different Timezone in Java

Tags: java, date, time, timezone-offset, java.util.date

I am confused with Timezone conversions in Java. I have a few cases which I will list out below.

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
   // sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/kolkata"));
    Date date1 = sdf.parse("2021-01-31");

    System.out.println(date1);   //. O/P - Sun Jan 31 00:00:00 IST 2021
```

Now lets uncomment the Timezone part and see the time difference

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/kolkata"));
    Date date1 = sdf.parse("2021-01-31");

    System.out.println(date1);  // O/P - Sun Jan 31 05:30:00 IST 2021
```

Now lets set the TimeZone to IST and see the time difference

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
    Date date1 = sdf.parse("2021-01-31");

    System.out.println(date1);   // O/P - Sun Jan 31 00:00:00 IST 2021
```

Now lets set the TimeZone to UTC and see the time difference

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    Date date1 = sdf.parse("2021-01-31");

    System.out.println(date1);  // O/P - Sun Jan 31 05:30:00 IST 2021
```

1. Can anybody please explain me why this shift in time is happening (+- 5:30) when I change the Timezone?
2. For IST and Asia/Kolkata, time should have remain same because they are same Timezone, but why the shift?
3. Why When using the UTC Timezone, time gets increased by 5:30 hours? What I understand is IST is 5:30 hrs ahead of UTC, so cnverting to UTC   should have decreased the time by 5:30 hrs
4. Why even after converting to UTC, my time displays IST 2021?

I still have confusion here.

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    Date date1 = sdf.parse("2021-01-31");
    System.out.println(date1.getTime()); // 1612051200000


    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    sdf1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata"));
    Date date2 = sdf1.parse("2021-01-31");
    System.out.println(date2.getTime());  // 1612031400000
```

Why instant of time in UTC is greater than instant of time in Asia/Kolkata ?

Comment: Your first step is to remove the old SimpleDateFormat and replace it with `DateTimeFormatter`

Comment: You should also consider what it is you are parsing, there is no time or time zone information in your string only date so what value are you trying to parse?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead just use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). And thereby get rid of all time zone trouble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some things for you to note:

- When a `Date` is printed, it will be formatted in your computer's local timezone (that's what `Date.toString` does). Presumably, your computer is in the Asia/Kolkata timezone, so the output is always displayed as a date & time in that timezone.
- A `Date` represents a *point in time* (i.e. an *instant*). It is ***not*** a tuple of year, month, day, hour, minute, seconds and timezone
- Since there are no time in your input string, the time 00:00:00 is used for the time when parsing.
- Just a date and a time is not enough to produce a point in time. You also need a timezone to specify a point in time. Since there is no timezone in your input string, the local timezone of your computer is used, or if you have set it, `sdf.getTimeZone()`.
- Although a timezone is used in parsing the date, the timezone is *not* part of the `Date` object.

> Can anybody please explain me why this shift in time is happening (+- 5:30) when I change the Timezone?

When you use the "IST" timezone (first and third code snippet), `sdf` gets the following pieces of information:

- Date: 2021-01-31
- Time: 00:00:00
- TimeZone: `Asia/Kolkata`

With these pieces of information, it can produce a point in time, represented by a number of milliseconds since the Java Epoch - 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC. *This is the `Date` object*. Then you print the `Date` object, which gets formatted to your local timezone. Your local timezone just so happens to be the same as the one that `sdf` is provided with, so you see `Sun Jan 31 00:00:00 IST 2021`.

When you use `UTC` (second and fourth code snippets), these information are provided to `sdf`:

- Date: 2021-01-31
- Time: 00:00:00
- TimeZone: `UTC`

That represents a different point in time than 2021-01-31T00:00:00 in Kolkata. How different? 2021-01-31T00:00:00 in UTC is exactly 5 and a half hours later than 2021-01-31T00:00:00 in Kolkata. Recall that to convert a UTC time to Kolkata, you add 5 and a half hours.

> For IST and Asia/Kolkata, time should have remain same because they are same Timezone, but why the shift?

Because you have misspelled `Asia/Kolkata`. The first "K" in "Kolkata" should be capitalised. Unknown zone IDs are treated as UTC by the `TimeZone` class. This is why you should move to the new `java.time` classes. `ZoneId` throws an exception if you supply it with an unknown zone ID.

> Why When using the UTC Timezone, time gets increased by 5:30 hours? What I understand is IST is 5:30 hrs ahead of UTC, so converting to UTC should have decreased the time by 5:30 hrs

You are thinking about *formatting* dates, not parsing, because remember that the timezone is not part of `Date`, but part of `SimpleDateFormat`. Your code does not format `Date`, only parses them. Without formatting, `Date`s are always printed in your local timezone.

To see your desired behaviour using `SimpleDateFormat`, you'd first parse the date string *once*, and then *format* it using `SimpleDateFormat`s with different timezones.

---

Really though, you should change to `java.time`. Using that API, your zone changing code could be written like so:

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = LocalDate.parse("2021-01-31")
        .atStartOfDay()
        .atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));
System.out.println(zdt);
ZonedDateTime utcDateTime = zdt.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
System.out.println(utcDateTime);

// output:
// 2021-01-31T00:00+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]
// 2021-01-30T18:30Z[UTC]
```

Comment: I understood everything except this point of yours.                                                          
That represents a different point in time than 2021-01-31T00:00:00 in Kolkata. How different? 2021-01-31T00:00:00 in UTC is exactly 5 and a half hours later than 2021-01-31T00:00:00 in Kolkata. Recall that to convert a UTC time to Kolkata, you add 5 and a half hours.    If I convert UTC time to Kolkata time, I add 5 and a half hours. That means UTC should be exactly 5 ans a half hours earlier than 2021-01-31T00:00:00 ? But you said its later?

Comment: @RandhirRay This is tricky to put in words isn't it? :) Let me try again... When you have the same _local date time_ (tuple of year, month, day, hour, minute, second), but different timezones, the _zoned date time_ in UTC is later than the one in Kolkata. On the other hand, when you have the same _point in time_ (x seconds since the epoch), and different timezones, the local date time in UTC will be an earlier local date time than the one in Kolkata. **Differentiating between local date times and points in time is very important!**

Comment: One more question that I have is '" If I have some date in String format, whats the best way to convert it to Date (or may be the new time classes) and store it in DB. My application uses 'serverTimezone=UTC' for MySql.

Comment: @RandhirRay Your code is doing the first thing I said in my last comment, whereas you might be thinking about the second thing. Please let my previous comment sink in your head for a few seconds, reread it a few times and confirm that it makes sense. :)

Comment: That depends on what information your string has. If it only has year, month, day like in your question, then you should store it as a `LocalDate`. I don't know enough MySQL to tell you how to do the DB side of things. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28897303/persist-java-localdate-in-mysql) will make sense to you? If it doesn't, you can try asking a new question.

Comment: I think I am getting the point now. So when we say local date time, we mean the Date value formatted in computer's local timezone?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213556/discussion-between-sweeper-and-randhir-ray).

Comment: Lets say I have only year. month and day, LocalDate is a good choice, What if i have the hour , minute and second too?

Comment: Seems to be having some problem in the chat.   So what I see in my console when I print the date object is nothing than local date time?

Comment: That's a zoned date time, which is basically a local date time plus a timezone. @RandhirRay Anyway, [I recommend you to read this section (and beyond) of this thingy that I wrote,](http://sweeper777.github.io/IRP/IRP.html#a-model-for-timezones) if you've got some time...

Comment: I would definitely read that. I would appreciate if you could guide me with some further reading too to understand the concept whole heartedly.

Comment: I don't know anything that's specific to Java, but the video that made me click was [this one](https://youtu.be/saeKBuPewcU). It uses NodaTime (a C# date and time library) terminology, but it shouldn't matter too much...

Comment: Thanks for all the knowledge sharing

Answer (score 2):

### java time

I recommend you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date work

```
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("2021-01-31");
    System.out.println(date);
```

Output is:

> 2021-01-31

A `LocalDate` is a date without time of day and without time zone or UTC offset, so using it frees you completely from all time zone trouble. Furthermore we don’t need any explicit formatter. Your string is in ISO 8601 format, and `LocalDate` parses the most common ISO 8601 variant as its default. As you can see, it also prints the same ISO 8601 format back when we print it, implicitly calling its `toString` method.

### What went wrong in your code?

The `SimpleDateFormat`, `TimeZone` and `Date` classes that you are using are poorly designed and long outdated. No wonder that their behaviour confuses you.

I am assuming that Asia/Kolkata (or Asia/Colombo or Asia/Calcutta) is the default time zone of your JVM. In your first example the `SimpleDateFormat` is using your default time zone and is parsing the string into the first moment of the day in that time zone.

In your second example, as Elavya has spotted so well, you have got a lower case `k` in `Asia/kolkata` which causes `TimeZone` not to recognize the intended time zone. And this is where `TimeZone` excels in bad design: it just tacitly gives you GMT instead. Next the `Date` class is poorly designed too and still prints the time in the default time zone of the JVM, giving the illusion that the `Date` object contains a time zone. This has confused very many. The start of the day in GMT is the same point in time as 05:30:00 IST, so this is what you get.

In your third and fourth example, even though the three letter time zone abbreviations are deprecated, IST (contrary to what Eklavya said) is interpreted as Asia/Kolkata and UTC as Etc/UTC. Even though as Eklavya also said, IST is ambiguous.

So in short:

1. The change happens because the start of the day is a different point in time in different time zones.
2. Because of your typo in `Asia/kolkata`. Time zone IDs are case sensitive.
3. You are not converting to UTC. You are parsing in UTC thereby converting *from* UTC, and `Date.toString()` further converts *to* Asia/Kolkata (IST) as the output also says.
4. Because the `Date` object hasn’t got a time zone and because `Date.toString()` grabs the default time zone of your JVM and uses it for rendering the string to be returned.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)
- [All about java.util.Date](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/)

Answer (score 1):

Java doc for [getTimeZone](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getTimeZone(java.lang.String))

> ID - the ID for a TimeZone, either an abbreviation such as "PST", a
>   full name such as "America/Los_Angeles", or a custom ID such as
>   "GMT-8:00". **Note that the support of abbreviations is for JDK 1.1.x**
>   **compatibility only and full names should be used.**

TimeZone abbreviation is not supported. So you can't use `IST`

And in TimeZone Doc for [Three-letter time zone IDs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html)

> For compatibility with JDK 1.1.x, some other three-letter time zone
>   IDs (such as "PST", "CTT", "AST") are also supported. However, **their
>   use is deprecated because the same abbreviation is often used for
>   multiple time zones** (for example, "CST" could be U.S. "Central
>   Standard Time" and "China Standard Time"), and the Java platform can
>   then only recognize one of them.

Problem is `IST` abbreviation is used for multiple time zones like Irish Standard Time, Isreal Standrad Time, Indian Standard Time. And you mistyped `Asia/Kolkata` as `Asia/kolkata`.

So, the GMT zone will return if the given ID cannot be understood from `TimeZone.getTimeZone()`

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to the accepted answer, for the last part of your question;

> Why instant of time in UTC is greater than instant of time in Asia/Kolkata in below code?

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date date1 = sdf.parse("2021-01-31");
System.out.println(date1.getTime()); // 1612051200000


SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
sdf1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata"));
Date date2 = sdf1.parse("2021-01-31");
System.out.println(date2.getTime());  // 1612031400000
```

- First, you have a point **T** in time regardless of timezone. In our example T=2021-01-31 00:00:00.
- When we set timezone as UTC and print the time using java.util.Date.getTime() method, it will print milliseconds since the Unix epoch, which occurred at midnight January 1st 1970, UTC. So it will print 1612051200000. **As you see the epoch and our date has the same timezone which is UTC**. So the time is printed directly, no adjustment necessary for timezone.
- Now, when we set timezone as Asia/Kolkata, during SimpleDateFormat.parse, timezone information will be added to date. That means +5:30h(19800000ms) will be added to time T. Therefore our time T is increased by 19800000ms. **However T must be pointing to the same point in time**. How do we fix that? It is fixed on SimpleDateFormat.parse method by subtracting 19800000ms from the time 1612051200000ms so that getTime() method will now show 1612031400000ms so that our actual time **T will still show the same point in time(which is 1612051200000ms)** because in this date object we have an extra 19800000ms which comes from timezone.